# How to get the branch/merge source & target from changelist in perforce?

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate, perforce-branch-spec

Using the API of perforce, I'm going over the history of all the changelists and I need to output a log with all the actions taken in perforce.

For Branching and Merging I want to log the source and target of the action but I can't seem to find it. Not in the changelist class nor in the FileMetaData class.

Perforce keeps the data in the history for every file that was effected by the change but I want to get the general action that was performed. e.g. Branch from //Main/Sample to //Main/Sample-Branch OR Merge from //Main/X to //Main/Releases/A.

Anywhere I can find this data?

Comment: Which API are you using?

Comment: What do you mean? This is how my code looks:
foreach (Changelist changelist in repository.GetChangelist(nextIndex))
            {
                foreach (FileMetaData fileMD in changelist.Files)
                {
                    LogActions(fileMD, changelist, folderPathes);
                }
            }

Comment: Which programming language are you using?  I know how to get the information you're looking for from the core server API (it's an integration record, which you'd get from "p4 filelog" or "p4 integrated"), I just need to know which of the derived APIs you're using to look up its doc and figure out how it's wrapped in your language of choice.  :)

Comment: I'm using c# as my language. Thanks a lot in advance :) If you need anything I will be highly available the next few hours :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [FileIntegrationRecord](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/AllMembers_T_Perforce_P4_FileIntegrationRecord.htm)(s) for the file revisions in the changelist as returned by [Repository.GetSubmittedIntegrations](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/M_Perforce_P4_Repository_GetSubmittedIntegrations.htm), or possibly the [RevisionIntegrationSummary](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/T_Perforce_P4_RevisionIntegrationSummary.htm) returned by [Repository.GetFileHistory](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/M_Perforce_P4_Repository_GetFileHistory.htm).

Comment: Click the links to get to the doc...?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which API you are using, but you will want to use the equivalent of the 'p4 filelog' command.

Example output:

```
//depot/release/prototype1/docs/Test Plan Template_Baseline.doc
... #1 change 471 branch on 2011/11/15 by jenbottom@resource_portle_dev (binary) 'Integrating to the prototype1 b'
... ... branch from //depot/dev/docs/Test Plan Template_Baseline.doc#1
//depot/release/prototype1/docs/associations
... #1 change 471 branch on 2011/11/15 by jenbottom@resource_portle_dev (text) 'Integrating to the prototype1 b'
... ... branch from //depot/dev/docs/associations#1
```

Taking a look at changelist 471, we can see what the actions on the files were, but not where they were branched from or to:

```
Change 471 by jenbottom@resource_portle_dev on 2011/11/15 22:04:33

        Integrating to the prototype1 branch in rel dir.

Affected files ...

... //depot/release/prototype1/docs/Test Plan Template_Baseline.doc#1 branch
... //depot/release/prototype1/docs/associations#1 branch
... //depot/release/prototype1/docs/changelog#1 branch
```

Hope this helps,
Jen.

Comment: Thanks for the try but as I wrote in the original question up here I have the ability to get the files list and the actions on each file. What you write you don't know is exactly what I don't know and what you write you know, I now as well :)